# Trying to fix AutoClicker error "No Module named Image"

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to run this guys code (https://github.com/okiyama/PyAutoClicker)  but I'm getting an error:

```
myles@myles-desktop:~/Desktop/PyAutoClicker-master$ python2.7 
autoClickGUI.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoClickGUI.py", line 9, in <module>
    from autoClicker import AutoClicker
  File "/home/myles/Desktop/PyAutoClicker-master/autoClicker.py", 
line 9, in <module>
    import pyxhook
  File "/home/myles/Desktop/PyAutoClicker-master/pyxhook.py", line 
41, in <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

I got both dependencies(PyuserInput & Tkinter) before trying to run the code with:

$ python2.7 autoClickGUI.py

I'd be very grateful with all help!

Comment: Might be a hidden dependency on PIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove this **import Image** from file pyxhook.py, cause it is not using this package anywhere in the entire script.

you can check this dependency by searching word Image in script pyxhook.py.